# Override the clone() method in generic SinglyLinkedList class

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, clone, adt

#### Override the clone method

When I try to override the clone() method in the generic SinglyLinkedList class to get a deep clone, I come across the following code. The fact that I have a little confuse about the  code.
See as follow:

```
 public SinglyLinkedList<E> clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // use inherited Object.clone() to create the initial copy
    SinglyLinkedList<E> other = (SinglyLinkedList<E>) super.clone( ); // safe cast
    if (size > 0) {
        // we need independent chain of nodes
        other.head = new Node<>(head.getElement( ), null);//Seems something wrong.
        
        Node<E> walk = head.getNext( ); // walk through remainder of original list
        Node<E> otherTail = other.head; // remember most recently created node
        while (walk != null) {
            // make a new node storing same element
            Node<E> newest = new Node<>(walk.getElement( ), null);//So as this one 
            
            otherTail.setNext(newest);
            // link previous node to this one
            otherTail = newest;
            walk = walk.getNext( );
        }
    }
    return other;
}
```

The definition of element:

```
E element;
public E getElement() {
  return element;
}
```

Since it is generic type, which means the getElement() may return an object, so, my question is should the code be rewrited as:

```
Node<E> newest = new Node<>(walk.getElement().clone(), null);
```

is there may be a CloneNotSupportedException? I am new to Java~
Thanks in advance!

Comment: These 2 lines are identical...  should they be?

Comment: Kent Pitman (one of the editors of the ANSI Common Lisp standard) has written a [short essay](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/PS/EQUAL.html) about this topic (albeit from a Lisp perspective, but the concepts apply here, too). Read the section title "Copying". The list class' author made a (somewhat) arbitrary decision; I happen to agree with the decision here, but it's still arbitrary. Also: objects are *not* clonable by default, so there is nothing, a generic container could call to clone the object, unless type parameter `E` is limited in some way to a class, which provides this feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking - as the answer seems too obvious.

The posted code clones the structure but not the objects in the structure. If you want to clone the objects too you must replace all `getElement()` calls with `getElement().clone()`.

Comment: The intention is to make a deep copy instead of a shadow copy. Actually I got the code from the book [DataStructure and Algorithm in java](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Michael-Goodrich/dp/1118771338/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1429280217&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=dataStructure+and+Algorithm+in+java), so I am just a little cionfused.

Comment: @shady - That sample is performing a shallow clone. A deep clone should clone all of the elements too as I suggested. *... We therefore create a new head node at line 5 of the code, and then perform a walk through the remainder of the original list (lines 8–13) while creating and linking new nodes for the new list.* this is a shallow clone, it is creating new nodes only.